# How can I can create a Configuration Bean programmatically with an external yaml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I created a small Spring Boot (v2.7.9) to try to creating bean programmatically.

I have a Configuration Class

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SimpleConfiguration {

    private String configName;
}
```

I have my Service

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private SimpleConfiguration simpleConfiguration;

    public MyService(ApplicationContext context, SimpleConfiguration simpleConfiguration) {

        this.context = context;
        this.simpleConfiguration = simpleConfiguration;
    }

    public String getSimpleConfigurationName() {
        return simpleConfiguration.getConfigName();
    }
}
```

and a very simple application.yaml file

```
config-name: "Nicolas Test"
```

I created a simple test, and SpringBoot can load the yaml, no problem.

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

        String name = service.getSimpleConfigurationName();
        System.out.println("n =" + name);
    }

}
```

Will return

```
n = Nicolas Test
```

I would like to know how I can use an external YAML file to generate Bean 'SimpleConfiguration' on the fly.

For example, I have a yaml file with

```
config-name: "External"
```

How can I created a Bean Simple Configuration with the configName property valued at "External".

The use case is I have a SpringBoot Project that run based on certain profile.

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active="env,run1" ...
java -Dspring.profiles.active="env,run2" ...
java -Dspring.profiles.active="env,run3" ...
```

and I would like to put run1, run2 and run3 file in a folder and run

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active="env" -Ddirectory=...
```

And the program would load run1 file, create necessary bean, then run, then clear connect and continue with file run 2 and file run3.

Thanks

Comment: check spring profiles https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Answer (score 1):

**[Use @Profile on a Bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)**

> Profiles are a core feature of the framework — allowing us to map our beans to different profiles — for example, dev, test, and prod.

> We use the @Profile annotation — we are mapping the bean to that particular profile; the annotation simply takes the names of one (or multiple) profiles.

> We annotate that bean with a dev profile, and it will only be present in the container during development. In production, the dev simply won't be active:

```
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class DevDatasourceConfig
```

Other way, using [@ConditionalOnProperty](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty) annotation

Comment: Thanks but that is for static configuration.
How could I add, then remove, a profile at runtime, and have all objects created with this profile?